# Retrieving DNS information of the localhost DNS information

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server-2003

In Windows, I find it somewhat difficult to access localhost dns server at localhost machine. I am finding no easy command line tool and so on.

So is there any command line tool that allows me to access windows DNS information easily?

I just need to find out the way to access dns information of the localhost (itself) machine, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such DNS server on windows machine until you install it as role(possible on server family only).

You will always have available **DNS client** which is responsible for resolving DNS queries.

> I am finding no easy command line tool and so on

What you want to achieve?

As **Serge** mentioned in his answer, you have **nslookup** which is almost on all platforms (linux, win, unix...).

So what kind of tool you are looking for?

You may read about [Domain Name System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows first.

**UPDATE**

you have several tools on windows while DNS role is installed:

- nslookup http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525
- dnscmd
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- General DNS tools http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753579.aspx
- netsh http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, you will find useful to use MMC snapin to manage your DNS server

- Using DNS MMC Snap-in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163507.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a machine with the DNS server role installed....

Answer (score 0):

open a command prompt and type

> ipconfig /all

The output lists the DNS the local machine is using.